# Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7 and standard Ruby 1.8 have overlapping gem paths

Tags: ruby

I installed Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7 on a Ubuntu server that already has the standard Ruby 1.8.6 install. They both put the same local user gem directory `/home/{username}/.gem/ruby/1.8` in their GEM PATHS. Is this safe and proper?

If not, is there a way to alter the GEM PATH of Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7 (but not Ruby 1.8.6) through an environmental variable so it doesn't include `/home/{username}/.gem/ruby/1.8` but instead something like `/home/{username}/.gem/ruby/1.8.7`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's unlikely that you'll have major problems with this as the gems are really the same for both. However, you should check out [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) as this is the type of problem it's intended to solve. As you try other ruby interpreters, you'll thank yourself.